# Numeric Keypad in JavaFXPorts

Tags: javafx-8, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have a javafx application to be deployed in android, I have a textfield in it, but instead of showing the default keyboard(letters,numbers,symbols), I just want to display numeric keypad. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `TextField`, you can call:

```
text.getProperties().put("vkType", "numeric");
```

Note that you need to use `-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx` to make it work.